# HQL function to get UTCdate and to extract date from timestamp

Tags: hibernate, hql, date-formatting

Is there a way to get UTC date in hql as like  `getutcdate()` function in MSSQLServer

and get date(2014-03-24) part as in MSSQLServer  (`CONVERT(varchar(20),getdate(),105))` or `DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,action_time),0)`) from 2014-03-24 20:56:26.297 in HQL